# Bind a click event to a :title in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, accordion

So I'm trying to bind the click event so it only runs when the actually href title is clicked on.  here is my code.

```
          <collapse :multiple-active="false">
          <div v-for="(campaign, index) in allCampaigns" :key="index">
                <collapse-item :title="campaign.campaign_name" @click.native.prevent="grabClientFacebookData(campaign.id)">
                <div v-if="spinner == true" style="text-align: center"><img src="../../../../img/spinner.gif"></div>
                  <div v-if="search == true">
                      <vue-good-table
                          :columns="columns"
                          :rows="tableData"
                          styleClass="vgt-table striped bordered"/>
                      <highcharts :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
                  </div>
                </collapse-item>
          </div>
      </collapse>
```

And here is the parent element:

```
  <div class="card card-plain">
<div role="tab" id="headingOne" class="card-header">
  <a data-toggle="collapse"
     data-parent="#accordion"
     :href="`#${itemId}`"
     @click.prevent="activate"
     :aria-expanded="active"
     :aria-controls="`content-${itemId}`">
    <slot name="title" @click.prevent="grabClientFacebookData(campaign.id)">
      {{title}}
    </slot>
    <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_minimal-down"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<collapse-transition :duration="animationDuration">
  <div v-show="active"
       :id="`content-${itemId}`"
       role="tabpanel"
       :aria-labelledby="title"
       class="collapsed">
    <div class="card-body">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</collapse-transition>
```

I am fairly new to vue and was wondering if it's possible.  My problem is that the click event shoots whenever any port of the collapse is clicked, not just the title.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping `{{title}}` in a span with the event bound to that? i.e.

`<span @click.prevent="grabClientFacebookData(campaign.id)">{{title}}</span>`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not.  Anything written outside of the <collapse-item> does not show in the main part of the accordion which I need.  Thanks though.